# ISO DateTime to Local DateTime using javascript

Tags: 2013, javascript, date-time

I have a ISO `DateTime` string `"2015-10-05T08:30:00"` getting through **REST** request. Now I need to convert it into my local `DateTime`. The way I am trying

```
var isoDateTime = new Date("2015-10-05T08:30:00");
var localDateTime = isoDateTime.toLocaleDateString() + " " + isoDateTime.toLocaleTimeString();
```

**Output is:** `10/5/2015 2:30:00 PM`.

Date is okay but the time is not. When I open this item in edit/display form, I got different date and it is actual date.

[image]

Comment: You might want to use moment.js and moment time zones, http://momentjs.com/

Comment: I haven't used it yet, but I know many who have and swear by it. Date manipulation is the worst in JavaScript, compounded by all the different date/time settings available in SharePoint.

Comment: Me too! Now searching to use

Comment: Have to read the documentation... Looking for others ways or who already faced this problem. Thanks @EricAlexander

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a magical solution! `Date.parseLocale(value, formats)` has solved my issue. There is no need to use third party libraries. See the details from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397521.aspx).

> Use the pareseLocale function to create an object of type Date from a
>   string. If you provide no custom formats, this function uses the
>   [Sys.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383763.aspx) property to determine the culture
>   value.

**Arguments**

> value: A locale-specific string that represents a date.
>
> formats(Optional): An array of custom formats.

**Return Value**

> If value is a valid string representation of a date, an object of type
>   Date; otherwise, null.